# Why is my phone connecting to local restaurants wifi?

Tags: wi-fi

I have an Android Galaxy S3. I have Norton 360 security. I did a scan last night, and it said I had connected to unsecured networks. One was Walmart, the other the Mexican restaurant across the street. I did manually connect to Walmart once, but I have never connected to the restaurant. I have never even been there.
Why is this happening and how to I make it stop. Thanks!!!!

Comment: **Settings -> Wi-Fi** -> three dots line -> **Advanced -> Use Open Wi-Fi automatically** -- disable it and see if the issue resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings - depending firmware  go to connections - more connection settings - turn off nearby device scanning. I'm thinking that may stop the auto connect you're seeing in Norton